# How should I link to HPC 2016 client dlls from my C# application?

Tags: c#, hpc, software-distribution

Our application can, if the client wants, distribute jobs to HPC. We use the HPC Client Utilities to do this. In HPC 2008 through 2012R2 the end user would install the HPC Client utilities and the dlls would be registered in the GAC. Our application finds them and uses them.

From HPC 2016 the HPC Client Utilities installation no longer registers dlls in the GAC. How should I link these dlls? I can install the 2016 nuget package for development - but can I redistribute the HPC dlls and all the dependencies via our installer? The license terms linked from HPC 2016 nuget page are the 2012R2 terms. The license put down as part of the 2016 Client Utilities installation seems to prohibit distribution unless you are a computer manufacturer.

If I can't redistribute the nuget package then how do I link to a dll that the end user could have installed anywhere on their machine?

I am failing so badly I can't even find the right place to submit a support request to Microsoft to find out redistribution rights...

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.HPC.SDK/) owners they have added the EULA for the HPC Pack SDK to their [license info](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43972/). This details redistribution rights. At the moment the EULA states only code marked as "Sample" can be redistributed...not that I can see any code in the SDK marked as "sample". It should mean that for 2016 onward you can bring the required HPC dlls with your software rather than requiring your clients to install the Client Utilities but it is not clear in the EULA. The package owners are investigating further. If I get updates I will post it here.